# Is it's possible to link all libs statically in one exe?

Tags: dll, d, dub

Now my project in D have a lot of different libs. Is it's possible to link them statically and make single exe (the size is not problem).

Which command I should pass to DMD or is there any way to specify it's in DUB config?

Comment: compile them at static libs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ratchet freak said, you will need to compile the dependencies as static libs themselves. Once you have the dependencies as static libraries, you can then list them in the `libs` entry of `dub.json` just as you would dynamic libraries.

It may not be a shining example, but [here](https://github.com/rcorre/terra-arcana/blob/master/dub.json) is a `dub.json` I use to manage a project that I want to create both static and dynamic builds of. I use the `configurations` section to separate the static and dynamically linked builds. When building, I use the `--config=` flag to choose between the static and dynamic build.

If you build static libs of the depenencies yourself and do not want to put them on your system's library search path, you can use the -L option in `lflags` to specify where the static libs are.

Note that compiling your immediate dependencies statically does not necessarily mean your project will have no dynamic dependencies -- it may still link dynamically to the dependencies of your dependencies (unless you compile those statically too). For example, the project I linked above is statically linked to `allegro` and its modules, but is still dynamically linked to dependencies of `allegro` like `libogg` and `libpng` (because I did not compile static versions of those).

Comment: So I need recompile all dub packages manually? I mean content of AppData\Roaming\dub\packages ?

Comment: As far as actual D libraries go, it should be as simple as changing the   `targetType` field of `dub.json`. This can be set to `staticLibrary` to force output as a static lib, but in my experience, simply setting it to `library` defaults to a static lib anyways. My answer may have mistakenly assumed you were talking about C libraries, which are more likely to be dynamically linked.

Comment: Could you explain me, why I can statically link with dynamic libs? They have not full import available?

Comment: @user1432751: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can't statically link to dynamic libs. You **can** have a program that is statically linked to some libs and dynamically linked to others, but the libs you link statically to **must** be static libs (as far as I'm aware).